# How can I stop an animation in jQuery and immediately start the next without the CSS wrapper getting left?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What I am looking for is to be able to click the buttons before the bounce animation is finished and have it start the next one.

I'm aware of jQuery's `.stop(true, true)` in order to stop the animation and jump to the end but I'm having trouble with the animation wrapper not being cleaned up. Anyone know a nice solution for this?

This is the basic jQuery code I have now and you can find the context in the jsfiddle below.

```
$(function(){
    $("#right").click(function(){
        var $next = $(".visible").next();

        if ($next.hasClass("slide")) {
            $(".visible").removeClass("visible").hide();
            $next.addClass('visible').show('bounce', { direction: 'right', times: 3 }, 500);
        }
    });

    $("#left").click(function(){
        var $prev = $(".visible").prev();

        if ($prev.hasClass("slide")) {
            $(".visible").removeClass("visible").hide();
            $prev.addClass('visible').show('bounce', { direction: 'left', times: 3 }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bQGtC/2/

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Hi Chris, just curious where about did you test out .stop()?

Comment: In the click event handlers before adding removing the class and doing the animation, much like what I used to fix it in the next fiddle except not dealing with the wrapper. It's pretty ugly but I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: Try adding them just before .show() for both functions {sorry lazy answer}

Comment: Well the problem is not in getting the animation to stop but rather getting the markup and css back to where it was before the animation. Feel free to look at my jsfiddle below to get a better picture of how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I have come up with one solution but it feels pretty damn hacky so I'm gonna hold off marking it as the answer in case someone else comes up with a prettier solution. This code can be DRYed up I know, I'm gonna refactor it some before/if I use it.

http://jsfiddle.net/bQGtC/7/